# cannot install tensorflow on anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

i am trying to install tensorflow on anaconda

i tried `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

but the installation stuck on `Solving environment:`

looked for a solution so someone suggested to install with debug

```
   conda install --debug -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

but it stopped on

```
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(277): tensorboard: pruned from 47 -> 0
```

[image]

how to fix this?

Comment: Which python version do you have?

Comment: @kushy the latest 3.7.2

Comment: Just out of curiosity: When you say that it stuck on `Solving environment`, what timespan are we talking about? Few minutes or like more than an hour? Just asking because recently, I remember that sometimes it took quite long for me until `Solving environment` finished, like up to 10-15 minutes, I'd say.

Comment: @kushy i think it was around 10 min and stuck on tensorboard: pruned from 47 -> 0 do u think i should have waited longer?!

Comment: No. I think the python version thingy is more probably the cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For python version 3.7, you need to first downgrade to 3.6 using `conda install python=3.6`. After that, the installation should work. I had a similar problem recently.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Tensorflow 1.12 supports python 3.4,3.5 or 3.6. 
python 3.7 is not supported.
you can download Anaconda 5.2.0
After the Anaconda is installed, you can use `conda install tensorflow` or `conda install tensorflow-gpu` to quickly install tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

What it worked for me was:
I uninstalled old versions of python and anaconda from my PC.
I installed anaconda (Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64.sh) from [here](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/).

I confirmed the conda installation by: conda -V

It should give you: conda 4.3.21

I confirmed the python installation by: python -V

It should give you: Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)

Confirm the conda environment by typing on anaconda prompt:

conda update conda

conda update anaconda

Next, I Installed theano by: conda install theano

Next, I installed tensorflow by: conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

Last, I installed keras by: pip install keras

This process takes some while.

Comment: This version of anaconda (Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64.sh) by default installs Python 3.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem many times and finally got the solution as follows for the latest anaconda

1. downgrade the python to conda install python=3.10
2. install tensorflow as conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow