# difference between "conda install python=3.6" and "apt install python=3.6"?

Tags: python, anaconda

Context: I have python 3.7 on my computer (Linux). Some package (tensorflow) needs a previous version of python to function.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233151/10973886), a user suggested to install a previous version of python using the command:

```
 conda install python=3.6
```

I am confused by this command, since I normally install python using apt or apt-get ( I am on ubuntu ). I think of python as being separate from anaconda.

```
 apt install python=3.6
```

What is the difference between these two commands?

Comment: In this reddit thread you will see that some persons use anaconda while others use the OS's package manager (apt) for main packages with the addition of virtual environments to manage their python dependencies. https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/6vq2m4/what_are_the_downsides_of_using_anaconda_vs/?rdt=43570&onetap_auto=true
 The choice of installing packages from conda or from apt + pip depends on many factors, such as for example: Can you maintain your own system? Do you work on data analysis?

Answer (score 2):

What you might want to do if you need a specific version of Python for a particular project is making a 'virtual environment'. Basically, that means that pip packages are installed within the project folder rather than in your `bin` folder somewhere on your computer. Virtual environment can also link to a version of python using something like `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.6`.

`apt install python=3.6` will install in the standard `bin` folder of your distro.

`conda install python=3.6` will check in which environment you currently are and install it there. It of course requires Anaconda installed and setup on your computer.

There are a lot of virtual environment management packages out there and I am not going to give an opinion on which is the best.

Note that if you install it using `apt install`, the version used in command line for `python3` or `python` may be ambiguous, to be sure, you can specify the full path or make an alias for that path if there isn't one.

Comment: Regular Python virtualenvs don't actually install new versions of Python, to be exact. They link the standard library and binaries of an existing Python installation into the virtualenv. If Conda allows one to do `python=3.6`, it may have a different mechanism.

Comment: Thanks! So just to clarify, what does conda install python=3.6 do if I have not specified a virtual environment? Does it then just install it for all environments?

Comment: I think `conda` uses the environment you setup when installing Anaconda. You should have an anaconda folder somewhere with the installs in it. But I am not sure.